# Xamarin Cannot compile: Parameter System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net-extensions, sqlite-net-pcl

I have a problem with a query of SQLite Xamarin

I have installed `sqlite-net-pcl 1.7.335` and `SQLiteNetExtensions 2.0.0`

The process of error is the next:

I fill the variable nuevoRegistro: [image]

```
dataService.InsertOrUpdate<PointOfSaleDTODBModel>(nuevoRegistro);
```

My model PointOfSaleDTODBModel:

[image]

I call the method and send it the variable nuevoRegistro

```
    public T InsertOrUpdate<T>(T model) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            var oldRecord = DataAccess.GetInstance().Find<T>(model.GetHashCode(), false);
            if (oldRecord != null)
            {
                DataAccess.GetInstance().Update(model);
            }
            else
            {
                DataAccess.GetInstance().Insert(model);
            }

            return model;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return model;
        }
    }
```

In this step is where i have the problem

```
    public T Find<T>(int pk, bool WithChildren) where T : class, new()
    {
        return connection.Table<T>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.GetHashCode() == pk);
    }
```

The error that get is the next:

[image]

Error Text:

- "Cannot compile: Parameter"
- `at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs) [0x00b16] in <d1788edcec634c19b907698bb77ed371>:0 \n  at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs) [0x001fb] in <d1788edcec634c19b907698bb77ed371>:0 \n  at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].CompileExpr (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] queryArgs) [0x0009d] in <d1788edcec634c19b907698bb77ed371>:0 \n  at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].GenerateCommand (System.String selectionList) [0x0005f] in :0 \n  at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].ToList () [0x00000] in <d1788edcec634c19b907698bb77ed371>:0 \n  at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].FirstOrDefault () [0x00007] in :0 \n  at SQLite.TableQuery`1[T].FirstOrDefault (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] predExpr) [0x00007] in :0 \n  at IDS.Helpers.DataAccess.Find[T] (System.Int32 pk, System.Boolean WithChildren) [0x0000e] in /Users/ingeneo/Documents/workspace/Xamarin/dms-mobile/dms-xamarin/IDS-only-login/IDS/Helpers/DataAccess.cs:120 \n  at IDS.Services.DataService.InsertOrUpdate[T] (T model) [0x00002] in /Users/ingeneo/Documents/workspace/Xamarin/dms-mobile/dms-xamarin/IDS-only-login/IDS/Services/DataService.cs:54`

Any help, thanks you

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for your code , it may solve the problem .

1. Use `SQLiteAsyncConnection`  instead of `SQLiteConnection`  , [refer to official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases) .
2. Use `Id` instead of `HashCode` to get data .

   ```
   Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
   ```